# auth0-react loginWithRedirect isLoading and isAuthenticated are false before isAuthenticated is true

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I have an auth component that checks if the user is logged in and if not, logs them in and redirects them without interaction.

```
import React from "react";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

const Auth = ({ redirectUri }: { redirectUri: string }) => {
    const { isLoading, isAuthenticated, loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0;

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("isLoading", isLoading, "isAuthenticated", isAuthenticated);

        if (!isLoading && !isAuthenticated) {
            loginWithRedirect({ redirectUri });
        }
    }, [isLoading, isAuthenticated]);

    return null;
};
```

When the user is already logged in, this works great and the `console.log` is:

```
isLoading true isAuthenticated false
isLoading false isAuthenticated true
```

So it correctly is loading until the user is authenticated.

However, when the user needs to authenticate, `isLoading` is `false` and `isAuthenticated` is false so it brings up the login page. After the user logs in and is redirected to the `redirectUri`, I get stuck in an infinite loop because `isLoading` is false and `isAuthenticated` is `false` before it is true. The `console.log`s look like:

```
isLoading true isAuthenticated false
// Here they are both false before the user is authenticated.
isLoading false isAuthenticated false
isLoading false isAuthenticated true
```

Because the `false` comes before the `true`, the user is redirected again, and again, in an infinite loop. Once I refresh the page, it works as expected like when the user is logged in.

I can't figure out why there's the `isLoading false isAuthenticated false` before `isAuthenticated` goes to `true`. It seems that `isLoading` should still be true if the authentication check isn't complete.

Comment: try useEffect(() => { ...}, [isLoading, isAuthenticated, loginWithRedirect]);